# How to select records not involved in a join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I need to make a query that returns some records not involved in a join, I paste the tables involved and the query that I wrote.

The tables are CAR and SPACE and the relationship is "one to many" (1 CAR in N SPACES ; in 1 SPACE 1 CAR)

RECORDS OF CAR TABLE:

```
........................................
car_id  | mark    | model   | prize
........................................
    1   | fiat    | 500     | 15000
    2   | fiat    | panda   | 8000
    3   | opel    | astra   | 20000
    4   | renault | clio    | 14000
    5   | opel    | corsa   | 12000
    6   | fiat    | panda   | 8000
    7   | fiat    | 500     | 15000
    8   | renault | capture | 16000
    9   | renault | clio    | 14000
    10  | fiat    | 500     | 15000
```

RECORDS OF SPACE TABLE (The primary key is identified by row, column and room_id. car_id is the foreign key of the primary key of CAR's table):

```
..................................................
   row  | column  | room_id | dimension | car_id
..................................................
    1   | 1       | 1       | 100       | 1
    1   | 2       | 1       | 100       | 1
    1   | 3       | 1       | 100       | NULL
    2   | 1       | 1       | 100       | 1
    2   | 2       | 1       | 100       | 1
    2   | 3       | 1       | 100       | NULL
    3   | 1       | 1       | 100       | NULL
    3   | 2       | 1       | 100       | 6
    3   | 3       | 1       | 100       | 6
```

Now, What I wanna get from the query is to select all the cars that aren't located in any space. I expect that the result is that table:

```
........................................
car_id  | mark    | model   | prize
........................................
    2   | fiat    | panda   | 8000
    3   | opel    | astra   | 20000
    4   | renault | clio    | 14000
    5   | opel    | corsa   | 12000
    7   | fiat    | 500     | 15000
    8   | renault | capture | 16000
    9   | renault | clio    | 14000
    10  | fiat    | 500     | 15000
```

This is the query that I wrote, but it didn't return the results that I expect.

```
SELECT car.* FROM car,space WHERE car.car_id = space.car_id AND space.car_id IS NULL
```

I'm learning the logic of the database only recently and unfortunately I'm not good, the query is totally wrong but I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using conflicting terms in the `where` clause:

```
WHERE car.car_id = space.car_id AND space.car_id IS NULL
```

But `space.car_id` cannot both be `null` and match `car.car_id`.

You're looking for a left join:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    car
LEFT JOIN
        space
ON      car.car_id = space.car_id
WHERE   space.car_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not in` to check the car id's in cars that are not in the space table. Because you have `null` values in the car_id column in the space table, the `where` clause filters them out.

```
SELECT car.* FROM car
where car_id not in (select distinct car_id from space where car_id is not null)
```

Or better use `not exists`.

```
SELECT c.* FROM car c
where not exists (select 1 from space where car_id = c.car_id)
```